# GCP - Autoscaling group - Instances at the creation

Tags: autoscaling, google-cloud-platform

I was wondering how GCP process the creation of an autoscaling group. Do they start with the minimum instances specified and evaluate the load and then adjust or the evaluate the load before launching the autoscaling group ?

---

```
max_replicas    = 5
```

### min_replicas    = 2

I just want to know if the size at the creation is fixed

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can do autoscaling on compute engine with 4 ways](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4av0.png)

When you choose an option that your needs and you can choose min and max instance number. The cluster will starting with your minimum VM settings. When your load increase than your cluster's VMs number will increase up to your max instance.